# Error al compilar programa en C en Visual Studio, lo detecta como virus

Tags: c, visual-studio, exe

Tengo un problema al ejecutar cualquier programa en C en Visual Studio.

Intento compilar un programa, y al ejecutarse arroja un error en la consola donde **dice que el archivo contiene virus o software malicioso**, destacando que son programas hechos por mí, y me ocurre con todos, incluso con algunos que había realizado en el pasado.

Intenté actualizando Windows, e incluso analizar los archivos por un antivirus y sale que están libres de virus.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo la siguiente extensión para poder compilar C, con tdm64-gcc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! probaste reiniciar la pc?? apagar el antivirus?

Comment: Intenta actualizar Windows y el antivirus. Normalmente son falsos positivos. Puedes cargarlo a https://www.virustotal.com/ para sacarte la duda. Y si crees que tienes algún virus haz un análisis o formatea el disco.